# Macro to run Macro

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to write VBA to run a macro if a criteria is met. The problem is that I can get it to run the first macro but then it ends!

Each macro is dependent on a true/false result in there own individual cell.

So far I have tried this:

```
Sub RUN_ALL_SET_SHEETS()


    If Range("C28").Value = False Then
                MsgBox "No Team Members Selected?"
                End

    ElseIf Range("C28").Value = True Then


    Dim Response As VbMsgBoxResult
    Response = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to set the sheets for the Team Members selected?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo)
    If Response = vbNo Then Exit Sub

    Else
    Return
    End If

    If Range("C10").Value = True Then
        Call Set_Sheet_Daniel
    End If

    ElseIf Range("C12").Value = True Then
        Call Set_Sheet_Gill
    End If

    ElseIf Range("C14").Value = True Then
        Call Set_Sheet_Hollie
    End If

    ElseIf Range("C16").Value = True Then
        Call Set_Sheet_Jo


    ElseIf Range("C18").Value = True Then
        Call Set_Sheet_Laura_H

    ElseIf Range("C20").Value = True Then
        Call Set_Sheet_Laura_K

    ElseIf Range("C22").Value = True Then
        Call Set_Sheet_Lucy

    ElseIf Range("C24").Value = True Then
        Call Set_Sheet_Mark

    ElseIf Range("C26").Value = True Then
        Call Set_Sheet_Richard

    Else

    End If

    Sheets("Header").Select

    MsgBox "Data Refreshed."


End Sub
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: how do you run the macro? it's not magically executed every time you change a cell value or what do you want?

Comment: "I can get it to run the first but then the macro ends" ...the first what? Time, `If` statement, etc. Can you please be a little more clear?  Also, it's outside the scope of this question, but FYI - looking at the `Set_Sheet_[name]` format you have, there's likely no need to have like, 10+ different macros. I assume instead you could do say, `Set_Sheet (Daniel)` where `Daniel` is passed through to the other macro.  That way you don't have to create a ton of extra subs if just a name is changing.

Comment: What you want is found [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/213612/how-to-run-a-macro-when-certain-cells-change-in-excel)

Comment: If/ElseIf are mutually exclusive.

Comment: The macro is run by manually running it via a button.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
Sub RUN_ALL_SET_SHEETS()


If Range("C28").Value = False Then
            MsgBox "No Team Members Selected?"
            End
ElseIf Range("C28").Value = True Then
Dim Response As VbMsgBoxResult
    Response = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to set the sheets for the Team Members selected?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo)
    ' Changed single line if statement here.
    ' Single line if statements wont go to an else.
    If Response = vbNo Then 
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Return
    End If

    If Range("C10").Value = True Then
        Call Set_Sheet_Daniel
    ElseIf Range("C12").Value = True Then
        Call Set_Sheet_Gill
    ElseIf Range("C14").Value = True Then
        Call Set_Sheet_Hollie
    ElseIf Range("C16").Value = True Then
        Call Set_Sheet_Jo
    ElseIf Range("C18").Value = True Then
        Call Set_Sheet_Laura_H
    ElseIf Range("C20").Value = True Then
        Call Set_Sheet_Laura_K
    ElseIf Range("C22").Value = True Then
        Call Set_Sheet_Lucy
    ElseIf Range("C24").Value = True Then
        Call Set_Sheet_Mark
    ElseIf Range("C26").Value = True Then
        Call Set_Sheet_Richard
    Else

    End If

    Sheets("Header").Select

    MsgBox "Data Refreshed."
End Sub
```

To build off of BruceWaynes comment, this seems like something better suited for a subroutine with args. That would look something like this:

```
Sub Sheet_By_Name(sName as String)
    ' This is just a demonstration. You would have to put your code
    ' in this block. This also assumes the same operation is needed
    ' for each name.

    ' Checks to ensure a sheet with the supplied name exists
    If Not ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sName) is Nothing Then
        ' Your code would replace this. It is best to avoid activate and
        ' select as is. Again, just for demonstration.
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sName).Activate
    Else
        msgbox "A sheet with the name " & sName & " doesn't exist!"
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```